# Split character by multiple criteria in R

Tags: r, split, character, criteria

I have a vector like that:

```
c("variable1+variable2 + variable3*variable4+ variable5")
```

I would like to split his string in a vector like:

```
c("variable1", "variable2", "variable3", "variable4", "variable5")
```

IMPORTANT 1: note that there are two kind of separators; + and *.
IMPORTANT 2: note that sometimes there are a blank space between the word I wanna get and the separator, and other times there are not blank spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `base R`, we can use `strsplit`

```
out <- strsplit("variable1+variable2 + variable3*variable4+ variable5", 
          "\\s*[*+]\\s*")[[1]]
```

-output

```
out
[1] "variable1" "variable2" "variable3" "variable4" "variable5"
```

The structure is

```
dput(out)
c("variable1", "variable2", "variable3", "variable4", "variable5"
)
```

Comment: This solution works for the "+" separator, but not for the "*" separator. I have tried this:
scan(text = c("variable1+variable2 + variable3*variable4+ variable5"), what = "", sep = c("+", "*"), strip.white = TRUE, quiet = TRUE)
but still doesn't work.

Comment: @Miquel i noticed your multiple sep only after i poste d the `scan`.  Changed to `strsplit`.  Please check

Answer (score 3):

You can use `stringr` package with

```
library(stringr)
a <- c("variable1+variable2 + variable3*variable4+ variable5")

str_split(str_squish((str_replace_all(a, regex("\\W+"), " "))), " ")
```

Output:

```
[1] "variable1" "variable2" "variable3" "variable4" "variable5"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another base R option using `strsplit` + `trimws`

```
> s <- c("variable1+variable2 + variable3*variable4+ variable5")

> trimws(unlist(strsplit(s, "\\*|\\+", perl = TRUE)))
[1] "variable1" "variable2" "variable3" "variable4" "variable5"
```